# Do child/sub classes have to be in their own separate file in order to test?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, hierarchy

I am using Eclipse to run this code program to test a Person class and its subclasses. In Eclipse it shows there are errors--that each child class must be defined in its own file.

I am learning Java, and would like to know if this is a must? Or can I make it work with parent and child classes all in one file? If I'm missing something, please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Here is my code: [I put this is all in one file on Eclipse]

```
import java.util.*;
//Test program to test Person class and its subclasses
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person = new Person("person");
    Student student = new Student ("student");
    Employee employee = new Employee("employee");
    Faculty faculty = new Faculty("faculty");
    Staff staff = new Staff("staff");

    //invoke toString() methods
    System.out.println(person.toString());
    System.out.println(student.toString());
    System.out.println(employee.toString());
    System.out.println(faculty.toString());
    System.out.println(staff.toString());
}
}

//Defining class Person
public class Person {
protected String name;
protected String address;
protected String phoneNum;
protected String email;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress () {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhoneNum() {
    return phoneNum;
}

public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail (String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name:"+getName()+"Class:"+this.getClass().getName();
}
}

//Defines class Student extends Person
public class Student extends Person {
public static final String FRESHMAN = "freshman";
public static final String SOPHMORE = "sophmore";
public static final String JUNIOR = "junior";
public static final String SENIOR = "senior";

protected String classStatus;

public Student(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public Student(String name, String classStatus) {
    super(name);
    this.classStatus = classStatus;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name:"+getName()+"Class:"+this.getClass().getName();
}
}

//Defines class Employee extends Person
public class Employee extends Person {
protected double salary;
protected String office;
protected MyDate dateHired;

public Employee(String name) {
    this(name, 0, "none", new MyDate());
}

public Employee(String name, double salary, String office, MyDate dateHired) {
    super(name);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.office = office;
    this.dateHired - dateHired;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getOffice() {
    return office;
}

public void setOffice (String office) {
    this.office = office;
}

public MyDate getDateHired() {
    return dateHired;
}

public void setDateHired(MyDate dateHired) {
    this.dateHired = dateHired;
}

@Override 
public String toString() {
    return "Name:"+getName()+"Class:" + this.getClass().getName();
}
}

//Defines class Faculty extends Employee
public class Faculty extends Employee {
public static String LECTURER = "lecturer";
public static String ASSISTANT_PROFESSOR = "assistant professor";
public static String ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR + "associate professor";
public static PROFESSOR = "professor";

protected String officeHours;
protected String rank;

public Faculty(String name) {
    this(name, "9-5 PM", "Employee");
}

public Faculty(String name, String officeHours, String rank) {
    super(name);
    this.officeHours = officeHours;
    this.rank = rank;
}

public String getOfficeHours() {
    return officeHours;
}

public void setOfficeHours(String officeHours) {
    this.officeHours = officeHours;
}

public String getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(String rank) {
    this.rank=rank;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name:"+getName()+"Class:"+this.getClass().getName();
}
}

//Defines class Staff extends Employee
public class Staff extends Employee {
protected String title;
public Staff(String name) {
    this(name, "none");
}

public Staff(String name, String title) {
    super(name);
    this.title=title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name:"+getName()+"Class:"+this.getClass().getName();
}
}

//Define class MyDate
public class MyDate {
private int month, day, year;

public MyDate (int month, int day, int year) {
    this.day=day;
    this.month=month;
    this.year=year;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a must. One class per file. Class can have inner classes. You can define subclasses as inner classes. But I recommend putting them in separate files and don't use inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be one class per file. Moreover, you are using the `MyDate` class in the `Employee` class, which you need to extend and you cannot extends more than one class, so it's better use the predefined `Date` class which is present `java.util.Date`. Import this in the `Employee` class.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

instead of this:

```
public Employee(String name, double salary, String office, MyDate dateHired)
```

use:

```
public Employee(String name, double salary, String office, Date dateHired)
```

There are some careless mistakes:
in Employee class

```
public static String ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR + "associate professor";
```

change to:

```
public static String ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR = "associate professor";
```

Similarly in faculty class

```
public static String ASSOCIATE_PROFESSOR + "associate professor";
```

put `=` instead of `+`.

Now this code will work.

Comment: Correction, there should be one **public** class per file. A file is allowed to have multiple non-public classes, although that is usually discouraged as it makes your code harder to discover.